# Set Static IP in CentOS 6.4?

Tags: networking, centos, ip

Most [guides](http://www.broexperts.com/2013/03/how-to-setup-static-ip-in-centos-6-3/) seem to revolve around modifying ifcfg-eth0, which doesn't exist on my system..

```
[root@Azaz07]# vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

[root@Azaz07]# ls /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/
ifcfg-lo     ifdown-ppp     ifup-ippp    ifup-sit
ifdown       ifdown-routes  ifup-ipv6    ifup-tunnel
ifdown-bnep  ifdown-sit     ifup-isdn    ifup-wireless
ifdown-eth   ifdown-tunnel  ifup-plip    init.ipv6-global
ifdown-ippp  ifup           ifup-plusb   net.hotplug
ifdown-ipv6  ifup-aliases   ifup-post    network-functions
ifdown-isdn  ifup-bnep      ifup-ppp     network-functions-ipv6
ifdown-post  ifup-eth       ifup-routes


[root@Azaz07]# /sbin/ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:480 (480.0 b)  TX bytes:480 (480.0 b)

p5p1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr C8:1F:66:03:00:7D  
          inet addr:192.168.0.14  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ca1f:66ff:fe03:7d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9818 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9634 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7020054 (6.6 MiB)  TX bytes:1665345 (1.5 MiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:18:8B:03:3C:59  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

How would I change my p5p1 adapter to static with the IP 192.169.0.55?

Also, why is it called a p5p1 adapter, instead of the seemingly more common eth0?

Running "setup" gives me a blank screen upon "Device configuration"

[image: Device configuration]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read about the new naming convention for devices here, titled: [Features/ConsistentNetworkDeviceNaming](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/ConsistentNetworkDeviceNaming). The change in naming conventions is also discussed in the official Redhat docs titled: [Appendix A. Consistent Network Device Naming](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6-Beta/html/Deployment_Guide/appe-Consistent_Network_Device_Naming.html). The convention now follows one based on location rather than arbitrarily `eth0`, etc.

> Change the network device naming scheme from ethX to a physical location-based name for easy identification and use

To change your IP address you can follow a couple of paths to do this.

1. Use NetworkManager ([see official RH docs](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-NetworkManager.html))

   You can find out what devices are under NetworkManager's juristiction.

   #### Example

   ```
   $ nmcli -p nm
   ======================================================================================
                                   NetworkManager status
   ======================================================================================
   RUNNING         STATE           WIFI-HARDWARE   WIFI       WWAN-HARDWARE   WWAN      
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   running         connected       enabled         enabled    enabled         enabled
   ```
2. Run the command `setup`, and change it through the GUI

   [image: ss 1]
      [image: ss 2]
      [image: ss 3]
      [image: ss 4]
3. Change the configuration file

   The file should be called `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-p5p1`. Simply change the line in this file to:

   ```
   IPADDR=192.169.0.55
   ```

   If this file doesn't exist at all, I'd simply create it and add content similar to the following:

   ```
   # /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-p5p1
   DEVICE="p5p1"
   BOOTPROTO="static"
   NM_CONTROLLED="no"
   ONBOOT=yes
   TYPE="Ethernet"
   DEFROUTE=yes
   PEERDNS=yes
   PEERROUTES=yes
   IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
   IPV6INIT=no
   NAME="System p5p1"
   IPADDR=192.169.0.55
   ```
4. Use the `network` service

   It's unclear to me if there are any downsides to using `/etc/init.d/network` service in addition to NetworkManager at the same time. In all my setups of CentOS 6 I have both running. But I generally make the `ifcfg-eth0` device files myself by hand.

   You could try making sure that this service is enabled and then try the steps above in #2 (using `setup`) to create the device afterwards.

   ```
    $ /etc/init.d/network start
   ```

   The `setup` GUI (actually it can be launched directly with this command: `system-config-network`) should be able to add devices and manage devices that have their configuration information kept in the `ifcfg-*` files under the directory `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`.

I highly suggest you at least familiarize yourself with the [Deployment Guide](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6-Beta/html/Deployment_Guide/part-Networking.html). It has a lot of useful information on networking using Redhat base products, which in turn will help with CentOS and Fedora.

#### So why's my network devices list blank?

I found this Fedora 16 issue that I believe is the issue you're experiencing (or is at least related). The issue is titled: [Bug 802580 - Device p21p1 does not show up in system-config-network](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=802580).

From the sound of this bug, the default behavior is to not create any of the `ifcfg-*` files unless you change some aspect of the settings via a networking GUI, such as NetworkManager - I believe. So you might need to try that, or follow the details I mentioned in options #3, above, and manually create the file yourself.

#### References

- [Redhat Deployment Guide for RHEL 6 - Part III. Networking](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6-Beta/html/Deployment_Guide/part-Networking.html)
- [CentOS no network interface after installation in VirtualBox](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78295/centos-no-network-interface-after-installation-in-virtualbox/78305#78305)

Comment: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-p5p1 doesn't seem to exist, see my output of that folder above.

Comment: Yes you need to create it, the device is most likely under control of NetworkManager. Those files are typically not created if NetworkManager is doing the controlling.

Comment: Thanks for adding screenshots. When I click "device configuration" I get a blank screen, unfortunately. http://i.imgur.com/mME6eVn.png?1

Comment: @some1 - see my updates and let me know if any of the additional info helps you out.

Comment: @some1 - what worked?

Comment: Well, I'm still not able to route with the static IP, but I'm considering that a separate issue. I'm able to set the IP statically two ways: System -> preferences -> network connections (is this network manager?) Also, a new file appeared in network scripts for some reason, I assume because I made changes in network manager: ifcfg-Auto_p5p1. If I modify that file manually, the IP changes on on /sbin/ifconfig. Like I said, I still can't route, but at least the adaptor is getting updated now.

Comment: @some1 - yes that pulldown is networkmanager's config dialog. OK, don't hesitate to ask a Q if you're stuck with the routing.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna fix that, you need to remove the package `biosdevname`:

```
sudo yum erase biosdevname
```

Comment: one-to-two line answers are really not too helpful. Please consider expanding your answer with supporting documentation or elaboration.