# How to connect to wifi after the installation of Scientific Linux 6.5

Tags: internet, scientific-linux

I just installed Scientific Linux 6.5, but it seems there is no way to connect to internet. How can I search and connect to wireless internet in my apartment?

Comment: Try this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78295/centos-no-network-interface-after-installation-in-virtualbox/78305#78305

Comment: This Q too will help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78295/centos-no-network-interface-after-installation-in-virtualbox/78305#78305