# Kali is in virtual box is not finding IP when booted as HostOnly. How to solve?

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux

I have setup Kali Linux in OracleVM.

When I installed the OS, its network type was NAT. But, when I changed that to HostOnlyNetwork, it is not finding its IP address.

Now when I changed it back to NAT, it is not connecting to the Internet.

How to solve this problem?

`ifconfig` terminal output:

```
root@kali:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:00:5a:0a  
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe00:5a0a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:19 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:3564 (3.4 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:732 (732.0 B)  TX bytes:732 (732.0 B)

root@kali:~#
```

Where has the IP address gone?

Comment: This is strange. Did you hard reboot your VM?

Comment: @shivams, what is hard reboot? I directly went to power-off.

Comment: @shivams, actually that didn't matter. I tested it again by properly shutting down and starting again. Same problem.

Comment: Hard reboot is nothing but shutting down your machine properly and then starting it again.

Comment: How about you try deleting the virtual machine but NOT ITS VIRTUAL HARD-DISK? Seems like some settings in your virtual machine have got messed up. Just delete it and create a new one using the same virtual hard-drive. Just beware that while deleting virtual machine, do not delete the virtual drive.

Answer (score 1):

This same problem has been covered here:

[CentOS no network interface after installation in VirtualBox](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78295/centos-no-network-interface-after-installation-in-virtualbox)

Although this changes due to the "host only," the cause/effect seems to be the same and is pretty common with new installs.

NOTE - the Link says "CentOS," but it's actually Ubunutu in the post, which is DEban as is Kali.

Cliff notes of the post is either to:

1) Use `$ nm-connection-editor` to open up the GUI for the network. Walk through the prompts provided based on your network, or:
2)use `vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` and change to

```
     ONBOOT="yes"
     NM_CONTROLLED="no"
```

Then reboot your machine.

Comment: While what you say appears as a valid possibility, it would justify flagging the question as a duplicate instead of answering it.

Comment: not sure if I even have enough points to do this - was just trying to be helpful :)